# How to assign "Access Results" permission per Webform?

Tags: webforms

On Drupal 7, my client would like to give a user to see a particular Webform's "Access Results". How can I assign the "Access Results" permission per Webform, beside using "Permissions per Webform"?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need [Permissions per Webform](https://drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform) module

You can set permissions per Webform as it suggests. Under the form settings.

Comment: Does this also set Webform View Permission? How to set those?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Webform access granular](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_access_granular) module.  This allow you to specify a specific user(s) per webform.